# I want to reset my form after clicking submit in reactjs. I have tried making another method. but it does not work

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, submit, reset

```
import React,{ useState} from 'react';
import { Button, Checkbox, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import axios from 'axios';
 
const Create = () => {
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
    const [checkbox, setCheckBox] = useState(false);
```

**Here I am sending data to a mock api I created**

```
const postData = () =>{
        axios.post(`https://61cb2af8194ffe0017788c01.mockapi.io/fakeData`,{
            firstName,
            lastName,
            checkbox
        })     
    }
```

**This is the method I created to reset the form but it does not work.**

```
const resetForm = () => {
        postData();
        setFirstName(" ");
        setLastName(" ");
        setCheckBox(false);
    }
```

This is my form where on click i am calling resetForm function but it is not resetting it
is sending the data but not resetting the form.

```
return(
    <div> 
         <Form> 
            <Form.Field>
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input  id="f1" placeholder='First Name' onChange={(e)=>setFirstName(e.target.value) } />
                
            </Form.Field>
            <Form.Field>
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input id="last1" placeholder='Last Name'  onChange={(e)=>setLastName(e.target.value)}/>
            </Form.Field>
            <Form.Field>
                <Checkbox id="c1" label='I agree to the Terms and Conditions' onChange={(e)=>setCheckBox(!checkbox)}/>
            </Form.Field>
                <Button type='submit' onClick={resetForm}>Submit</Button>
        </Form>
        <br></br>
        <Button onClick={()=>navigate(-1)}>Go Back</Button>
    </div>
    
  )

}

export default Create;
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually it will reset the form, the problem is you do not use Controlled Components to show the latest update value in UI

you should bind the value like this:

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

You can refer the doc here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 1):

You can reset your form using the native `form.reset()` method.

```js
const Create = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  const resetForm = () => ref.current.reset();

  return (
    <div>
      <Form ref={ref}>
        <Form.Field>
          <label>First Name</label>
          <input id="f1" placeholder="First Name" onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)} />
        </Form.Field>
        <Form.Field>
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <input id="last1" placeholder="Last Name" onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)} />
        </Form.Field>
        <Form.Field>
          <Checkbox
            id="c1"
            label="I agree to the Terms and Conditions"
            onChange={(e) => setCheckBox(!checkbox)}
          />
        </Form.Field>
        <Button type="submit" onClick={resetForm}>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form>
      <br></br>
      <Button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>Go Back</Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Create;
```

Comment: Or, you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/formsy-semantic-ui-react, which wraps semantic-ui components with formsy form validation

Comment: It doesn't work. Also i want to send the data at the same time to api

Answer (score 0):

For that, you have to set `value` property in your `input`. Try this

```
const Create = () => {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");
  const [checkbox, setCheckBox] = useState(false);

  const postData = () => {
    console.log(firstName, lastName, checkbox);
  };

  const resetForm = () => {
    postData();
    setFirstName(" ");
    setLastName(" ");
    setCheckBox(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Form>
        <Form.Field>
          <label>First Name</label>
          <input
            id="f1"
            placeholder="First Name"
            value={firstName}
            onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Field>
        <Form.Field>
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <input
            id="last1"
            placeholder="Last Name"
            value={lastName}
            onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Field>
        <Form.Field>
          <Checkbox
            id="c1"
            label="I agree to the Terms and Conditions"
            checked={checkbox}
            onChange={(e) => setCheckBox(!checkbox)}
          />
        </Form.Field>
        <Button type="submit" onClick={resetForm}>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Can you accept my answer and upvote, if it helped?

Comment: I did upvote. It needed at least 15 reputation.